# Session id in Tomcat Cluster

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, session-replication

I have a basic concept question about tomcat cluster. That is, if I have a tomcat cluster with two machines ( we say, m1 and m2 )

If I access a webpage in m1 with the url : http://192.168.0.10:8080/examples/test.jsp , I will get a session id ( we say, s1 )

Then, I access another webpage in m2 with the url : http://192.168.0.11:8080/examples/test.jsp , I will get a session id ( we say, s2 )

If I have already configured the session replication functionality, are the s1 and s2 equal ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And in fact when you visit a page in `m2` will you not get any session ID. Tomcat `m2` will simply read your cookie and associate the request with the existing (replicated from `m1`) session.

Comment: Even for the different url, the session id will be the same? And I search for the post on the web, they usually use the same machine with various tomcat instances and different port.

Comment: Yes, assuming that both tomcats serve through the same host. I think that port doesn't play any role on the cookie, but in any case, at the end you'll need to serve both tomcats through a proxy under the exact same host:port combination.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I must to check the configuration of the tomcat cluster session replication.